# Jquery detect change to either imput or select option

Tags: jquery

I have two elements on a page:  an HTML  Tag and a select option. I wish to monitor both for changes, so that once a person has clicked both, i can do an action.

```
<select name="pets" id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>

<a  class="cancelItem" href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

I am able to detect one of the elements with a click event, but not sure how to add an event monitor to also monitor the change event for the select option.

i.e:

```
  $(".cancelItem","#pet-select").click(function(event){
    
                event.preventDefault();

       alert('Item cancelled');

}
```

The problem with above is that the selection option should be a change event rather than a click event

Comment: simple  ! `$("#pet-select").on("change", function(e){ /* your logic code change here */});`

Comment: @Spring i want to monitor both at the same time

Comment: add the above code below your code , so it'll listen to both

Comment: @theSeeker You can not do that because both events are different. You can do that if both event are same. You have to make both event separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement to call same click function for multiple elements using the following code:

```
$('#pet-select').on('change',function(event){
  trackEvent(event);
});

$('.cancelItem').on('click',function(event){
    trackEvent(event);
});


function trackEvent(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event);
  alert('Item cancelled: ' + event.type);
}
```

In the trackeEvent, using event object you can track either select or click event occured using **event.type**

Comment: Thanks for reply Sagun. but should the #pet-select not be a change event. I read that you should not use a click event for select options.

Comment: There is not `click` event for `<select>` tag in jQuery. but it sould be `change`

Comment: @theSeeker I have updated the code, you can check above.